# Is there a 'select between tags' shortcut in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Notepad++ I used this extension that when I was inside the  arrows of any tag in html, I could use a keyboard shortcut to select either only the contents of the tag, or also include the tag into the selection.

Ie.

```
<div>
  div content
</div>
```

When I'm in  tag I would like to select div content without using mouse to do the selection.

I've seen some suggestions of using the shift+alt+right arrow shortcut, but it really isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The built-in command *Emmet: Balance (outward)* does what you want. It selects content of a tag and then progressively includes the tag and works outward just like *Expand Selection to Tag* in Sublime, and sounds like the extension for Notepad++.

You can create a custom keybinding for it as well in the preferences, for example

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+a",
        "command": "editor.emmet.action.balanceOut"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this compatible with editor.action.smartSelect.grow?  I'd love to use the same key combo for both no matter how they are nested.

Comment: @shs I wonder if it could behave differently in the context of JSX/HTML and JS. I would also prefer to use single set of keyboard bindings for both.

Comment: @jodyfanning Tried the key bindings, works better than expand_region extension but it's kinda slow, almost half a second (.5s) comparing to `expand_region` selection action/trigger. Is there a way to make the selection faster?

Comment: Great answer - although a brief explanation about running Emmet commands (for the uninitiated) would be helpful :)

Answer (score 10):

Click **twice** on **Shift+Alt+Right Arrow(→)** should do the trick.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On macOS this is ⌃⇧→ (control + shift + right arrow)
Highlight the start tag, then use the keyboard shortcut and it will highlight to the closing tag of that element. Works with multi-select too!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the extension [expand region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).  It does what you want quite nicely.  Works for html and javascript.

Comment: Tried it before I posted my OT, really doesn't do at all what I need :/. Is almost the same as shift+alt+right arrow shortcut.

Comment: ?  Shift-Alt-Right seems fairly useless to me.  The extension is very different.  Using the default key binding successive Ctr-W's do exactly what you say you want for me.  And their html demo on that link isn't what you want?  It progressively adds to the scope of the selected region.

Comment: The selection takes too many steps. I simply need one shortcut. To select the div and it's contents.