# Select all text between two tags in an HTML file, using VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use **Visual Studio Code** to open an HTML file and select all the text blocks that have a specific tag, in order to copy only that text to a separate file.

For example, let's assume I want selected all the blocks of text that lie between `<span class="c4">` and `</span>`.

Is there a native way of doing this, or, eventually, using a plugin?

**Edit**: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46120662/2248320), but the answers only deal with ONE selection of text (the question is for a keyboard shortcut). What I need is to select in one go ALL the text blocks that fit the criteria.

Comment: ***IF*** your html does not have nested `span` elements, you MAY be able to use this find: `(?<=span class="c4">)(.*?)(?=<\/span>)`.  And then `Alt+Enter` would select all those matches and you can copy them.  In general, regex is a bad way to find tags in html but if your file is simple it may work fine.

Comment: How about just growing your selection using `alt + shift + right arrow` until you selected what you want? Growing your selection should respect the tags and only grow inside of them first... Use  `alt + shift + left arrow` if you grew the selection too far.

Comment: @Mark: It works, except that sometimes the HTML code is "borken" in several lines. For example, I have also `<span class="c4"` in one line, and `>` is on the next line, so here it does not work.